# After booting, GRUB loader appears but no login screen. just a blank screen stays. Tried almost all methods of ubuntu desktop repair

Tags: 18.04, grub2, gnome

I am in IT support and totally new to Ubuntu.
I have faced an issue on two ubuntu machines in the last two days,
The issue is that when we turn on the PC, Ubuntu won't start, and GRUB loader will appear, in one machine user can log in through the "normal boot" option in recovery mode. but in the second machine, even recovery mode doesn't work.
I've tried update, upgrades, all tools dpkg, fsck, etc in recover mode but all in vain.

Please guide.

Comment: If they used to work before, then an update might have broken some of their (graphic?) drivers (included in the kernel). To check, when the grub menu comes up, choose the entry "Ubuntu with advanced options". A sub-menu will appear, listing at least two pairs of entries with different kernel version numbers; one without, and one with "recovery mode" appended. Pick the normal entry (not recovery) but the lower kernel number (previous kernel version). See if that yields some different result. If yes, update your question with the findings.

Comment: If the machines use proprietary graphics drivers, we should be informed about that. The following command will reveal the info: `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display'`. Use Ctrl+Alt+F3 to access a virtual console, where after logging in with the normal user's credentials, you can run the command.

Comment: Also, if the machines have different symptoms, then it will be very difficult to follow your story through just this one question. Optimally, you could ask a separate question to for the machine that's less trivial to sort out.

Comment: I've tried both kernal version you mentioned, with and without recovery mode. but it gives the same output. a black screen, or a purple screen without anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

Has the system worked in the past or is it a new installation?
You may try to see if the base system starts by hitting ctrl-alt-F1. This will give you a text login. Login as user, use sudo su to change to root and then the command dmesg will dump the most recent startup log. Look if something looks bad.

Comment: On recent versions with GDM (comes with default installation), the virtual consoles can be accessed via Ctrl+Alt+F3 — Ctrl+Alt+F6. What you mentioned, Ctrl+Alt+F1 is the GDM login screen.

Comment: I use lightdm, apparently they differ in that regards. Good point.
Still the output of dmesg is (normally) a good source to information of failing kernel modules.